# Html page jump from div

Tags: html

Hey guys I am looking for help in regards if i am doing my code right i want to page jump to a section on the same page but every time i click on these links nothing happens.

```
<div align= "center" id="topdiv">
<a href="resta.html">|HOME|</a>
<a href="#pasta" id="back"><b>|PASTA DISHES|</b></a>
<a href="#pizza"><b>|PIZZA DISHES|</b></a>
<a href="#sandwhiches"><b>|House Hero Sandwhiches|</b></a>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say 'page jump', are you talking about jumping to a section of the same page, or loading up a new page?

Comment: to a section of the same page

Comment: Your `#pasta`, `#pizza` and `#sanwhiches` sections are set up correctly in that regard then. Do you have corresponding elements that have those words as the `ID`? Could you please update your question to showcase a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#pasta{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 600px;
  background: pink;
}

#pizza{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 500px;
  background: skyblue;

}
#sandwhiches{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 700px;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div align= "center" id="topdiv">
<a href="resta.html">|HOME|</a>
<a href="#pasta" id="back"><b>|PASTA DISHES|</b></a>
<a href="#pizza"><b>|PIZZA DISHES|</b></a>
<a href="#sandwhiches"><b>|House Hero Sandwhiches|</b></a>
</div>

<div id="pasta">
  PASTA
</div>
<div id="pizza">
  PIZZAA
</div>

<div id="sandwhiches">
  SANDWidthweradfsdf
</div>
```

You can make like this.